# Error: Type 'FontFeature' not found. Flutter google_fonts package error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, google-fonts

When using the latest version of google_fonts (6.2.0) package in flutter project, I'm facing this 'Type FontFeature not found' issue:

```
/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-6.2.0/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:69:8: 
Error: 'FontFeature' isn't a type.
  List<FontFeature>? fontFeatures,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried downgrading the package version but the issue persists.
Also tried flutter clean and pub get..

Comment: Did you import "dart:ui"?  I seem to remember needing to do some special import with FontFeature.

Comment: There was [an issue](https://github.com/material-foundation/flutter-packages/issues/567) raised an hour before yours. When you downgrade packages, make sure to remove the caret (^) in front of the version number. For example: `google_fonts: 6.1.0`

Comment: yeahh.. 6.0.0 is working fine for me..

Comment: if you are starting a new project. this issue can be solved by just upgrading flutter with flutter upgrade command.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To everyone facing this issue, downgrade to an older version 6.1.0 (recommended) to get this issue solved.
Also, keep this in mind:

> When you downgrade packages, make sure to remove the caret (^) in front of the version number. For example: google_fonts: 6.1.0

Thanks to [@Dhafin Rayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13625293/dhafin-rayhan) for pointing it out.

Comment: if you want to install specific version you have to remote ^

Answer (score 7):

use this google_fonts: ^5.1.0 this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using google fonts package version above 6.1.0 in pubspec.yaml file then downgrade it to 6.10 or more lower then this issue will be resolved.

Note :  remove the  ^ this as well.

Example  google_fonts: ^6.2.0   =>    google_fonts: 6.1.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the `google_fonts` package.

Change the package version in `pubspec.yaml` from `^6.2.0` to `6.1.0`

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the google_fonts package. If you are using google fonts package version above 6.1.0 in pubspec.yaml file then downgrade it to 6.10 or more lower then this issue will be resolved.

Change the package version in pubspec.yaml from ^6.2.0 to 6.1.0

Note: Also remove caret (^) icon as well from the front of version number.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can try use this `google_fonts: ^5.1.0` this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

por garantia roda um flutter clean, apaga o pubspec.lock e rodem novamente o flutter pub get. e não pode esquecer de tirar o "ˆ" antes de rodar o flutter pub get.

Comment: The answer should be in English, but I'm not sure

Comment: please try to answer in english.

Answer (score 0):

I tried other solutions including the ones to downgrade but they either created new problems or the particular font I was trying to use was not available.

I just had to upgrade flutter using the "flutter upgrade" command in the terminal and that worked in my case. Would recommend doing this before resorting to alternative troubleshooting methods.